# Get Error in deviceToken for push notification in iphone sdk?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I have got error from push notification in iphone sdk when i have use apns.

regards,
Nikunj Akabari.

Comment: didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError this delegate Method call when i have use apns.

Comment: ok then just paste this code inside that method and reply with your output      NSLog(@"Push notification failed with the following error : %@",[error localizedDescription]);

Comment: ok dude but i have found this type error like Push Notification Failed with the following error no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application

Comment: hi @Hrushikesh where you test your application in simulator or in Device?

Comment: Are you using a simulator or device?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, I understand that problem lies in the **provisioning profile**. So you just delete your profile from **xcode** and install a fresh downloaded profile from apple developer account.Normally it will solves your problem. If else you need to check whether your provisioning profile included push notification correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Check your certificate provisional profile also enable push notification for your app
also make sure test it in real device not simulator

for more detail please follow

[reywenderlinch](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/)